# How do you change the name shown in Task Manager for a running process (in particular a sub-process of the main executable)

Tags: windows, process, task-manager, win32

Unlike on Linux or macOS, I haven't been able to find an API to change the process name of a running process (or in the case I care about, a sub-process).   I'd want it to still appear under the main program (which I don't care about changing).

I need to do this from within the program, not from a batch script or by hand.

Note that Edge appears to do this, so there must be a way -- but it might be a hidden/non-public API...

Comment: Issues specific to programming and software development are off topic, see [on-topic](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) . Try [SO] but please first read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).